# How to get this position?

Tags: java, android

How call to this method `OnClick`? I really tried, but i'm noob for this.
`getAdapterPosition` its not possible? How to get this?

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
android.view.View.OnClickListener  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    CheckBox buttonShare;
    buttonShare = findViewById(R.id.button_shared);
    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(this);


public void onClick(android.view.View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_shared:

            shareWallpaper(wallpaperList.get(getAdapterPosition()));

            break;
    }
}

public void shareWallpaper(Wallpaper w) {
   findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(w.url)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                          #blabla
                      }
                  }
            );
}
```

> shareWallpaper(wallpaperList.get(getAdapterPosition()));

Comment: What is this method `getAdapterPosition()` for?

Comment: I got it from an adapter that has a similar function

Comment: getAdapterPosition is for RecyclerView.Adapter or the classes extending it. You can't use it for an Activity directly

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please explain us how you show your wallpaper, and how you handle wallpaper change.

Comment: @LincolnMoreira What you actually wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Solution for onClick method. change this

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
```

to

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

then in OnCreate method do

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CheckBox buttonShare;
    buttonShare = findViewById(R.id.button_shared);
    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            shareWallpaper();
        }
    });
}
```

2) You cannot call getAdapterPosition() directly there is no such method.It's in the adapter class so do

```
adapter.getAdapterPosition();
```